# NPM module curlrequest producing Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected

Tags: node.js, post, npm

I have been searching around trying to resolve the following issue:

I am doing a curlrequest using the npm module 'curlrequest'

I am looping thru an array of id numbers and each id is then used to make a outgoing POST request to a remote server using this module 'curlrequest'

I am getting the following error:

```
        curl.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
               ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
```

With the following warnings:

```
(node:21363) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 finish listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:21363) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 unpipe listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:21363) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:21363) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:21363) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My specific solution did not really solve this exact issue , but i decided to just stop using this module and switched over to standard request library.